# The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to setup hot module reloading in a react/typescript (with TSX) environment. I have used [the react/redux real-world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) as a model in getting things going, and this is what I have so far:

**server.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

var app = new (require('express'))()
var port = 3000

var compiler = webpack(config)
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }))
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.info("==>   Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port)
  }
})
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        path.resolve('./src/index.tsx'),    
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './index.html' })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
    },
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Root from './containers/root';

render(
    <Root />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**containers/root.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Root extends React.Component<void, void> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <p>boom pow</p>
        );
    }
}
```

Changing `<p>boom pow</p>` to `<p>boom boom pow</p>` in the root element kicks off this in the javascript console in the browser:

```
[HMR] bundle rebuilding
client.js?3ac5:126 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 557ms
process-update.js?e13e:27 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
process-update.js?e13e:81 [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)
This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves. See http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html for more details.
process-update.js?e13e:89 [HMR]  - ./src/containers/root.tsx
process-update.js?e13e:89 [HMR]  - ./src/index.tsx
```

I've stepped through [these steps](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md) as best I can tell, but am still having no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where all the "hot" part in your config and code? 'react-hot' of the loader, 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server' on your entries, hot: true on your webpack dev server compile config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as mentioned by commenters, was missing in my loader - I'm not sure if this had anything to do with it, but I also switched to using babel after typescript - and having typescript compile to ES6. New config below:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        path.resolve('./src/index.ts'), 
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve('./src/index.html') })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.tsx?$/, 
                loaders: [
                    'react-hot',
                    'babel?presets[]=es2015',                  
                    'ts-loader'
                ] 
            },
            {   test: /\.json$/, 
                loader: 'json'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if someone still struggles with this see the readme: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware/blob/master/README.md

> This module is only concerned with the mechanisms to connect a browser client to a webpack server & receive updates. It will subscribe to changes from the server and execute those changes using webpack's HMR API. Actually making your application capable of using hot reloading to make seamless changes is out of scope, and usually handled by another library.

`webpack-hot-middleware` doesn't handle hot reload, you'd need to use `react-hot-loader` for example